# How to transpose columns when they encode multiple "records"?

Tags: openrefine

I have a spreadsheet I have imported into OpenRefine. The creator encoded groups of information (records) in columns. I need to bring each of those groups of columns into its own row, along with all the relevant columns.

Using a simplified example, how would I go from this:

```
id  foo1  foo2  foo3  bar1  bar2  bar3
1    4     6     a     7     9     b
2    5     5     a     8     8     b
3    6     4     a     9     7     b
```

To this:

```
id  foobar1  foobar2  foobar3  
1    4         6        a     
1    7         9        b   
2    5         5        a     
2    8         8        b     
3    6         4        a     
3    9         7        b
```

I've been trying to think of a way forward with intermediate columns, but there are are 6 groups of 5 columns and I'm currently stuck.

---

I found a solution. The steps are:

1. Concat each group of columns into a single column (FOO_CONCAT, BAR_CONCAT)
2. Delete the now unneeded columns (foo1..3, bar1..3)
3. Transpose your CONCAT columns into a single column, no prefix, ignoring blanks, filling down other columns
4. Now FOO_CONCATs and BAR_CONCATs are all in the same column
5. Split that column into several columns...(using the separator you used in step 1)
6. Rename columns
7. Strip out prefixes (I had foo1:4, bar2:8, etc for clarity)
8. Transform to numbers (Edit cells -> Common Transforms -> toNumber)
9. Now you're ready to transpose,facet, etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is essentially the same has the solution you describe, but possibly with some shortcuts to avoid all the steps.

Given the example data you post I would:

1. On "Id" column select Edit column->Add column based on this column
   from menu
2. Make new column name "foobar"
3. Use the GREL `forEach(row.columnNames,cn,if(cn.startsWith("foo"),cells[cn].value,null)).join("|")+"~"+forEach(row.columnNames,cn,if(cn.startsWith("bar"),cells[cn].value,null)).join("|")`
4. Once new "foobar" column exists, on this column use menu option Edit cells->Split multi-valued cells using the "~" character (as used in the GREL above)
5. The also on the "foobar" column use menu option Edit columns->Split into several columns, using the "|" character as in the GREL above
6. Finally on ID column use menu Edit cells->Fill down

This should result in the output you describe - if you don't need the original columns at this point you can either remove them, or (sometimes quicker) export the first X columns that have the reconfigured data using the custom tabular exporter, and then import that data into a new project.

You can modify the GREL to deal with the exact column groupings you have. In my example I've used the column naming to group the values, but if that isn't the reality of the data you are dealing with you can use GREL like:

```
forEach(row.columnNames.slice(1,4),cn,cells[cn].value).join("|")+"~"+forEach(row.columnNames.slice(4,8),cn,cells[cn].value).join("|")
```

Which uses the 'slice' function to select certain columns rather than using some aspect of the column name to select them.